# Add default value for one entity for tenants from host in AspNetBoilerPlate

Tags: multi-tenant, aspnetboilerplate

**Scenario :** 
My multitenant project is based on ASPNetBoilerPlate. 
I have a "WORK" entity which is IMayHaveTenant. Every tenant must see default Works which is in HOST And also His Works too every where. How I must do that? 
I need some codes like : `tenantId == id || tenantId is null`

**Wrong Answer** :

```
using (CurrentUnitOfWork.DisableFilter(AbpDataFilters.MayHaveTenant)){    }
```

This returns other tenants Works too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an interface, inherit `IMayHaveTenant` if you want the other built-in features that are for it:

```cs
public interface IMayHaveTenantSharedWithHost : IMayHaveTenant
{
}
```

Implement that interface:

```cs
public class Work : Entity, IMayHaveTenantSharedWithHost
{
    public int? TenantId { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

Override `CreateFilterExpression` in your `AbpDbContext` subclass and handle that interface:

```cs
protected override Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> CreateFilterExpression<TEntity>()
    where TEntity : class
{
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression = null;

    if (typeof(ISoftDelete).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TEntity)))
    {
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> softDeleteFilter = e => !IsSoftDeleteFilterEnabled || !((ISoftDelete) e).IsDeleted;
        expression = expression == null ? softDeleteFilter : CombineExpressions(expression, softDeleteFilter);
    }
    
    // if (typeof(IMayHaveTenant).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TEntity)))
    if (typeof(IMayHaveTenantSharedWithHost).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TEntity)))
    {
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> mayHaveTenantFilter = e => !IsMayHaveTenantFilterEnabled || ((IMayHaveTenant)e).TenantId == CurrentTenantId || ((IMayHaveTenant)e).TenantId == null;
        expression = expression == null ? mayHaveTenantFilter : CombineExpressions(expression, mayHaveTenantFilter);
    }
    else if (typeof(IMayHaveTenant).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TEntity)))
    {
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> mayHaveTenantFilter = e => !IsMayHaveTenantFilterEnabled || ((IMayHaveTenant)e).TenantId == CurrentTenantId;
        expression = expression == null ? mayHaveTenantFilter : CombineExpressions(expression, mayHaveTenantFilter);
    }

    if (typeof(IMustHaveTenant).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TEntity)))
    {
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> mustHaveTenantFilter = e => !IsMustHaveTenantFilterEnabled || ((IMustHaveTenant)e).TenantId == CurrentTenantId;
        expression = expression == null ? mustHaveTenantFilter : CombineExpressions(expression, mustHaveTenantFilter);
    }

    return expression;
}
```

Comment: Awesome ... That works!